# The connection type "OLEDB"...not recognized as a valid connection manager type

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I am sporadically experiencing the error message below with one of my SSIS packages.  The package is run on a schedule by the SQL Server Agent.  The error is basically stating that the connection type (OLEDB) is not valid.  This error seems to occur randomly once or twice a day causing the SQL Agent job to terminate.  The same package completes successfully throughout the day when the error does not occur.

I have set DelayValidation to true for the connection manager already.

Just for a bit more context, the the connection string for the offending connection manager is set at runtime.  Also, "PackageA" in the error message below is being executed by another package.

> Executed as user: domain\svcacct. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5571.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  7:40:00 AM  Error: 2020-01-13 07:40:40.63     Code: 0xC0014005     Source: PackageA      Description: The connection type "OLEDB" specified for connection manager "Destination" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type. This error is returned when an attempt is made to create a connection manager for an unknown connection type. Check the spelling in the connection type name.  End Error  Error: 2020-01-13 07:40:40.63     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: PackageA      Description: Error loading value "

**EDIT**

I also see the error below occurring.  I'm wondering if there is some common underlying cause? This [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/administration/800703fa-illegal-operation-error) describes the error below.  Note that the service account that runs this SQL Job is never logged on interactively as described in the article--at least to the best of my knowledge.  But I am curios as to whether or not somehow the account is being logged out in the middle of the job and then things go awry.

Any suggestions other than just trying the suggested resolution in the article for the second problem?  Has anyone ever had these 2 problems occur on the same box and fixed both issues in this manner?

> The package failed to load due to error 0x800703FA "Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion."

Answer (score 0):

Solving the error that states 'The package failed to load due to error 0x800703FA "Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion."' seems to have resolved both problems.

The solution can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/800703fa-illegal-operation-error.

In a nutshell, I enabled the "Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff" setting in the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).

I'm not sure why the registry keys were being unloaded to begin with.  The article mentioned above states

> This problem typically occurs after an administrator uses a service account to log on to the server for an interactive session, and then logs off.

However, no one was logging onto the server for an interactive session using the service account.

Nevertheless, enabling the setting has resolved both issues.